# How to make bootstrap3's navbar's input size to fill with the rest of the space?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use the input group in navbar-form, like following code:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="product" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

It got fixed size about 200px in firefox. However, in chrome or safari, the search takes a whole new line. I want to know does bootstrap's css control the input's width.

input-group-btn got two css setting, display: table-cell; width: 1%. What are these for?

In the docs, the default search bar is:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It works both fine in firefox or chrome, but I want it to take the rest of the navbar's space. Like facebook's search bar.

I am a individual developer, I am not good at front end design, Does anyone know anything about this particular request?

Comment: I do have the same problem! @Mik378 solution is alright but doesn't make it match all the available space. Looking forward for finding a solution! Maybe an issue should be risen on Github?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue just now.

I use Safari and unfortunately, the form element takes the whole line (100% of the size) (however on Firefox, it doesn't).

A simple and easy fix would be to precise the form's width below 100%.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" style="width:40%" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="product" type="text">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Search</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note: `width-40` class instead of the `style` attribute doesn't fix it...don't know why however.

Comment: I get what you mean, it's a great solution, I have to manage the percentage to the right number, thank you very much

Comment: Same thing was happening to me but in my case I wasn't using a form, just the div with the "input-group" class and I needed to put a style="width: 120px" to it in order to prevent it to go to 100% on focus. Thanks for this, is a similar issue but the solution is almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Chrome bug (see [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9950)). There is no need to using hard CSS. You can fix it by:

**.less**

```
@media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
  .navbar-form {
    .input-group-btn,
    .input-group-addon {
      width : auto;
    }
  }
}
```

or **.css**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-form .input-group-btn,
  .navbar-form .input-group-addon {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this... (this example shows one way to use Bootstraps Navbar)

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="z-index:11000">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li> - your nave items would each be placed into here </li>
          <li> - your nave items would each be placed into here </li>
          <li> - your nave items would each be placed into here </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You can place the form tag inside one of the list item tags instead of classifying the nav bar as a form itself.

Comment: It has nothing to do with li.

Comment: maybe i am not clear of your question then. i was under the impression you wanted the nav bar to the whole width, but really just the input to fill the rest of the space, my apologies.

Comment: you could try setting the input using bootstrap's class="span3" (example) instead of manually.